# Two-step functions in R

Tags: r

I want to graph and practice and a simple two-step function (the staircase function). I've constructed a random dataset below for a running start. My x-variables are given below.

```
a=c(1,3,5,7,9,11,12)
b=c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14)
```

My y variables are:

```
y=c(1/7,2/7,3/7,4/7,5/7,6/7,7/7)
```

Any suggestions for codes, or references, would be extremely helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `geom_segment` from the package `ggplot2` as follows

```
plotData <- data.frame(x=a,xend=b,y=y,yend=y)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plotData) + geom_segment(aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend))
```

producing

[image]

If you want to join the steps, bind an additional df with data for your lines to plotdata like

```
joinLineData <- data.frame(x=b[-length(b)], xend=a[-1],y=y[-length(y)],yend=y[-1])
plotData <- rbind(plotData,joinLineData)

ggplot(plotData) + geom_segment(aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend))
```

producing
[image]

Comment: Hi thanks, is there a way I can join them?